# Error checking as navigating though UI

Tags: selenium, navigation

I have a number of objects which are used repeatedly as navigating though the pages of web application.  I check each page for an error dialog as I navigate.  As I repeatedly use these tests, if I do encounter an error, each test case which uses the navigation functions will fail.  I don't want to maintain two sets of navigation functions so I am wondering if anyone knows of a good approach to take?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not do assertions in your navigation classes. As much as I understand from you question, you have at the moment something similar to:

```
class Navigation{
    public void navigateToSomePlace(){
        navigate();
        assertTrue(isInExpectedPlace());
    }
}
```

But you should remove the validation from that method and implement it as a separate method which you can call when you need it. If you want better explanation, show some code.

---

Edit, how I would implement it:

```
class Navigation{
    public void navigateToSomePlace(){
        navigate();
    }

    public void validateIsInSomePlace(){
        assertTrue(isInExpectedPlace());
    }
}
```

So basically, when you are doing the navigation test you would call both of them, but if you only use it for navigating, you would only call the navigate()

Comment: thanks Eriki. I guess in that case I would need two sets of test cases.  One to perform the navigation and one to do error navigation?  The code snippit you provided matches more or less the approach I was taking.

Comment: I have edited the answer. And yes, I personally think that you should have separate testcases for navigation testing. If you want to always validate the navigation, I would start by questioning that why would you run the exact same tests more than once. This will become a performance issue when your testsuite grows big.

Comment: thanks.  The reason was to try and keep the tests modular so that any individual test can be run at a time.